# System of linear equations with modulo elements

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, systems-of-equations

Transform the following $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ into reduced row echelon form (with $[1]$ as Pivot element and $[0]$ above the Pivot element). State out the Modulo elements through representatives $x$ with $0 \leq x \leq 4$.

$A =: \begin {pmatrix} [1] & [1] & [2]\\ [0] & [2] & [4] \\ [2] & [4]& [3] \end{pmatrix}$

My  idea:

$\begin {pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 2 & 4& 3 \end{pmatrix} (III-2I) = \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix}  III-II = \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} II \cdot [3] = \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}~~~~~~~~ I-II = \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

How to go on?

Comment: Hollie mollie! Please do drop those annoying little square parentheses: just write *clearly* that you're talking about the equivalence classes modulo whatever and that's all.

Comment: You have a mistake, I believe, at the rigtmost lower entry after the very first equality. It must be $$3-2\cdot 2=-1=4\pmod 5$$ and then automatically your matrix is singular...:)

Comment: You edited 9 minutes ago, yet you left unchanged the mistake I remarked in my comment above...

Comment: Is this correct so far?

Comment: Yes, though the last step is, imo, unnecessary and, imo, even wrong if what was wanted it row reduction *only*

Comment: no, i have to transform it into  reduced row echelon form

Comment: Exactly, @fear.xD : one matrix before your last one you *already* finished since that matrix is already in row echelon form! In fact, even the matrix before the one before the last one's already in row echelon form. What you did next is to normalize the diagona, which isn't a must (unless told otherwise by your teacher). But your very last step is completely unnecessary and even wrong (it all depends on how you define and do things)

Comment: Not row echelon, reduced row echelon form (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) $[1]$ has to be Pivot, and above the Pivot their must be $[0]$

Comment: Ok, I see....then yes: you're done in your last step.